# iPod Model #1238 will not charge

Tags: ipod, battery, charge

I have an iPod Model #A1238 in which the battery is low. I tried to connect the power adapter cable which was provided to try to charge it but no luck. I thought it was the power cable so I bought a new one but tried to charge the iPod with it, still nothing. I then used the new cable and connected it to my daughter's iPod, that one charged just fine.

How do you get the port fixed so that it will charge again? 
Where do you get the parts to fix it since I can't find them on the internet?
And will my music collection of over 9,000 mp3 survive the change out?

-80GB paper weight.

Comment: This answer may prove useful for your query about your music collection. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74675/if-i-replace-an-ipod-classic-battery-myself-will-the-music-be-preserved/74693

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of the question:

You must have a backup of your songs on iTunes..?

Now, if you replaced the charger and you confirmed that it works, the battery in you iPod might have a problem.
I would recommend going to a Service Center and getting it checked out.

By the way, even if you don't have a backup of songs on your Computer, they can probably extract data from the Drive in your iPod.